# AJAX post not saving, and is refreshing the page without any console logging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

With the form, the submit button refreshes, has yet to save, and is not logging anything for some reason..

..though the same style AJAX post is working in another app, with almost identical HTML..

There have been recommendations to remove the form tags, and change the submit button to input type="button"...though with this the page literally does nothing

The API (NodeJS) is working properly, as tested with Postman..

Here's the HTML (am using handelbars templating, both server-side and client-side):

```
<div id="allStories" class="allStories"> </div><!--/allStories-->
<script id="storyTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

  <div class="thisness">
      <div class="stories">

          \{{#each stories}}
              <input type="text" class="formFormat" value="\{{ story }}"/>
          \{{/each}}

          <form id="newStoryForm">
              <input type="text" id="newStory" placeholder="…" />

            <br><button type="submit" class="btn" id="AddStory">add</button>

          </form> <!--/newStoryForm-->

      </div> <!--/stories-->
    </div> <!--/thisness-->

</script>
```

And Here's the AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // GET ALL
    // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

    function foundAllSuccess(resJSON) {

        var templateSource = $("#storyTemplate").html();

        console.log('Getting All the stories..');
        console.log(templateSource);

        var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

        var storyHTML = template({stories: resJSON});

        $('#allStories').html(storyHTML);

        console.log('All is Proper');

    }

    function foundAllFailure() {
        alert(textStatus + "**:**" + errorThrown);
    }

    function refreshStories(){

        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:4200/api/v1/stories",
            method:'get',
            success: foundAllSuccess,
            error: foundAllFailure

        })

    }

    refreshStories(); // gets called when the page loads


    // POST
    // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

    // AddStory button clicks, adding new story    
    $( "#AddStory" ).click(function() {

        // story element for API
        var story = $( "#newStory" ).val();    
        console.log(story);

        var AjaxPostData = {
            story : story
        };

        // if the story field has content
        if (story.length != 0) {
          console.log('there is a story: ' + story);
            // make an ajax call
            $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            data: AjaxPostData,
            type: 'post',
                url:"http://localhost:4200/api/v1/stories",
                success: refreshStories,
                error: foundAllFailure
            });
        };

        console.log(AjaxPostData.story);

    });

}); // doc is ready
```

Comment: this doesnt look right to me. if the form has no action, why use a form at all? Just use a button. Also `var story = $( "#newStory" ).val();` doesn't look right since #newStory is the form itself and not a form element

Comment: @chiliNUT good look with #newStory, meant for the form id to be different from the field id.. Even so, it still does not post.. And without <form> nothing happens at all?

Comment: If you are using ajax, then I don't think the form should be posting at all. I'm not understanding why you want to submit a form at all if you want to use ajax

Comment: @chiliNUT Non-javascript fallback?

Comment: @chiliNUT ok, but without <form> nothing happens.. how do I get this to send data without the <form>?

Comment: The form has nothing to do with sending data, its all happening in your click event. Remove the "`<form>`" tags, make the `input type=submit` into just `input type=button`, run it again, note any messages in the console, and report back. make sure "persistent" is on in the console

Comment: @chiliNUT literally nothing reports, anywhere, when removing the form tags.. Even after changing the input type to 'button'.. any suggestions?

Comment: @chiliNUT any thoughts as to what's going on with this? Appreciate your time with this

Comment: i couldnt really say anything else without a fiddle or something

Comment: @chiliNUT Here's the start of a fiddle.. though could use some help getting the ajax working on jsfiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/76mWt/1/

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment. So, i am proceeding with assumption. There are three things that i want to point out.

One, click handler should be updated to submit handler on the "form". Also, please do not remove "form" tag and "button type="submit". As these tags help in screen reader software and auto fill functionality of browsers.

Second, click handler is bound in ready event, at that time this button is not present inside DOM. So, we have two options here, either put click handler (change it to submit handler, as submit button fires both event, first it fires submit event and then click event) inside the foundAllSuccess at the last line or use jQuery "on/live" method to attach submit handler.

Third, in the click/submit handler, do event.preventDefault() and at last line do return false.

Hope this helps.